Есть ли возможность отправлять события в яндекс метрику, не подключая ее как библиотеку?
Хочу подключить яндекс метрику в android приложение, но если подключать ее как зависимость то она поднимает отдельный сервис который нагружает приложение, увеличивает вес приложения на ~100мб и возникают краши приложения, в исходниках не нашел конкретных ендпоинтов на которые можно отправлять события.
Нашел в документации Post API, но там написано что данные можно отправлять только после того, как они были отправлены по SDK, так что такой метод не подходит
ссылки:
Исходный код метрики
гайдлайн от яндекса

Вы бы хоть ссылку дали, где вы это вычитали. Как по-вашему SDK работает? Так же само общается с сервером через REST, просто нужно выяснить как аутентифицировать запросы.

@woesss добавил

Там речь об API получения данных, естественно их можно получить только после отправки. API отправки они не предоставляют в открытом виде, но всё что нужно при желании можно найти в исходниках. Но я не думаю что свой велосипед обойдётся вам дешевле чем, SDK и правильно настроеннаяой обфускация.

Такого варианта использования нет документации, соответственно нарушите п.5 и вас забанят. https://yandex.com/legal/metrica_termsofuse/?lang=ru
